# How and where to add sqlite(.db) file in to an android project

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android. Now, I am trying to work with database. I got many tutorials for manipulating Sqlite database operations. But my doubt is that where should I add the .db file in to the application. In package explorer window of IDE, under which folder group I need to add the .db file? I hope you understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add your database file in assets folder.

Comment: Or you can create the database onCreate with standard sqlite query language

Comment: you can add your db file in the assets folder. If it solution isn't true, should describe your problem.

Comment: But how to add in to the asset folder? When I right clicked on the asset item inside the Package Explorer, I couldn't find any option to Add. Is there any other way, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically I am an iOS developer. In the case of iOS, we will creating an sqlite file inside the project folder and add it to the resource folder inside the Package Explorer. How this has to be done in Android?

Comment: u need to put ur database(whicch is .sqlite extension) in ur project's asset folder

Comment: thanks for all you comments. I understood.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you already have **.db** file then put that file in **assets** folder or **raw** folder

Then you have to copy that file at path **/your.package.name/data/data** directory
for further use.

Otherwise you can create new database using code...

see [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) example....

Comment: ok. But physically do I need to keep the empty database file inside the project folder?

Comment: thanks for accept see this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Do we have to create assets folder if not exist?