# Where to place an existing database in my project

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use an existing sqlite database in an Android - Android Studio based projects. I've done a search on Google an some suggests placing it in the 'Assets' folder. However in the project structure there is no such folder. The folder structure in the project is as follows

> -res
>   --drawable
>   --layout
>   --menu
>   --mipmap
>   --values

Should I just add the 'Assets' folder or should I place my sqlite db file in a different location.
Disclaimer: I'm new to Android Studio and android development

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579798/how-and-where-to-add-sqlite-db-file-in-to-an-android-project

Comment: please read my problem description more thoroughly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for creating asset folder **File**->**New**->**Folders**->**Asset Folder**
you can place your pre-created db in there

Answer (score 7):

The 'assets' folder is at the same level than 'res', not inside it. You can simply create a folder there using your regular file explorer and then put your sqlite there. Android Studio will see that folder and file.

EDIT: showing better:

```
+ main
++ assets
+++ db.sqlite
++ java
++ res
```

Answer (score 2):

This image might help. Control (or Option) click on the "app" folder to bring up the menu, then navigate to Assets Folder.

[image: Control-click(MacOS) on the "app" folder to bring up the menu...]