# how to connect sqlite database with an android project

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have created an SQLite database by using DB Browser for SQLite.
I want to connect this database with my android project ..
So, where should I put it ? in which folder of my project ?
and how can I connect them together ? just with SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and where to add sqlite(.db) file in to an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579798/how-and-where-to-add-sqlite-db-file-in-to-an-android-project)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, please look at the link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You really have to search before asking. If you did, you'd find an answer less than in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, where should I put it ? in which folder of my project ?

Typically you'd put the database file into the assets folder or within a folder within the assets folder.

> how can I connect them together ? just with SQLiteOpenHelper ?

You would typically then connect to the database after copying the database from the assets folder to a suitable location (easiest place is in data/data//databases).

Although you could do the above via a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, there is a simpler way by using [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Instructions are in the README.

- Note the database file needs to be copied into the **assets/databases** folder as that is where SQLiteAssethelper expects the file to be.

Comment: Where is the assets folder? I couldn`t find it .. also data/data

Comment: You may need to create assets folder app/main/src if using AssetHelper no need to worry about looking for data/data it will place the db into it. As it basically uses getDatabasepath() method, which will result in data/data/package_name/databases/