# Possible to put SQLite database in project folder in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am working on an android app for school that requires user account, sign up, and login functionality. I was wondering if it is possible to save the SQLite database file into the project folder instead of into the device that it is running from. For example, if I insert an entry into the database on one emulator, and I start the app on another emulator that entry will still be there.

Is it possible to store an SQLite database into the project folder with the source code?

Comment: No it is not possible. You can store the database in your project, in assets folder, but you will have to copy it in the device or emulator if you want to use it for any database operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and where to add sqlite(.db) file in to an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579798/how-and-where-to-add-sqlite-db-file-in-to-an-android-project)